# Intel XDK how to build for iPhone only?

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store-connect, intel-xdk

I'm trying to build an iOS app using intel XDK. My Application works fine in iPhone but it's giving me a bug when being executed with iPad, so that's blocking my app to the App Store, as Apple reviewers notice this bug.

What I want to do is to build my app only for iPhone, I don't want it to run on iPad. How can I do this? Where do I set this on Intel XDK? Is it on Itunes Connect?

Comment: Even if you build your app as an iPhone only app (not a universal app) then it must run on the iPad at iPhone resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no proper way to do this through intel XDK. What you have to do is go do your additions.xml and over iOS part you add one of these tags:

```
<preference name="target-device" value="tablet" />     <!-- Installs on iPad, not on iPhone -->
2
<preference name="target-device" value="handset" />    <!-- Installs on iPhone, iPad installs in a zoomed view and doesn’t fill the entire screen -->
3
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />  <!-- Installs on iPhone and iPad correctly -->
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set preference in your additions.xml. there are 3 options

1. install on ipad not on iphone
2. install on iphone in iPad installs in a zoomed view and doesn’t fill the entire screen
3. install on iphone and ipad